# Изменение пароля у пользователя wordpress

Tags: wordpress

подскажите пожалуйста. Хочу обновить пароль у пользователя - реализовать его изменение.

пишу так:

```
wp_update_user(array('ID' => $user_id, 'user_pass' => wp_hash_password($user_data['new_password'])));
```

Потом пытаюсь авторизоваться и пишет что пароль неправильный. Выяснил что хешь не правильный. Регистрация происходит при помощи плагина.

Answer (score 1):

В свойство `user_pass` необходимо задавать пароль в явном виде, а не его хэш. Хэш посчитается автоматически.
А у вас получается, что пароль в БД сохраняется как хэш от хэша пароля. Логично, что введение пароля при авторизации будет приводить к ошибке.

Делайте так:

`wp_update_user(array('ID' => $user_id, 'user_pass' => $user_data['new_password']));`

или ещё один вариант, если необходимо поменять только пароль:

`wp_set_password($user_data['new_password'], $user_id);`

Comment: Сделал так. Заработало. Но теперь после изменения выводит такую штуку: http://pastebin.com/g0RGnTrZ 

Что это значит?

Comment: Это у вас что-то с http-заголовками. Погуглите по запросу `headers already sent`. Вот, например, статья на тему http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/headers

Comment: Разобрался в чём беда. Это из-за того что я вызывал функцию `wp_update_user`. Она возвращает `id` пользователя. Сделал `wp_set_password` ошибка пропала. Спасибо.

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/586808/paid-membership-pro-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F