# Paid Membership Pro изменение пароля

Tags: php, wordpress, auth, failedlogin

Установил плагин Paid Membership Pro. Нужно сделать изменение пароля — 3 поля: старый пароль и два поля под новый.

добавил форму в /wp-content/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/pages/billing.php.
Создал функцию в functions.php плагина.

Функция:

```
function pmpro_change_password($user_id, $user_data) {

    global $wpdb, $current_user;

    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php');

    $user = get_userdata($user_id);

    if($user_data['new_password'] != $user_data['old_password']) {
        if($user_data['new_password'] == $user_data['new_password_repl']) {

            $pass_hash = wp_hash_password($user_data['new_password']);

            $old_pass_hash = wp_hash_password($user_data['old_password']);

            $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);

            $user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);

            if($wp_hasher->CheckPassword(trim($user_data['old_password']), $user->user_pass)) {

                //wp_logout();

                wp_set_password($user_data['new_password'], $user_id);
                $_POST = array();

                $current_user = wp_set_current_user($current_user->user_login);
                wp_set_auth_cookie($current_user->ID);

                do_action('wp_login', $current_user->user_login, $current_user);

                return 'Пароль успешно изменен!';
            }else{
                $_POST = array();
                return "No, Wrong Password";
            }
        } else {
            return 'Пароли не совпадают!';
        }
    } else {
        return 'Пароль не должен совпадать с текущим!';
    }

}
```

Проблема заключается в том что после изменения пароля при обновлении страницы нужно опять логинится. И выводится такая ошибка:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /customers/4/d/c/testofsite.nu/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/realestate2/header.php:5) in /customers/4/d/c/testofsite.nu/httpd.www/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 892
```

Что я делаю не так? как правильно?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка возникает из-за функции `wp_set_auth_cookie()`, она работает с http-заголовками. Попробуйте вместо неё использовать `wp_signon()` или `wp_authenticate()`:

```
wp_signon(array(
'user_login'    => $current_user->user_login,
'user_password' => $user_data['new_password'],
'remember'      => true, // или false, если не нужно запоминать пользователя
));
```

или

```
wp_authenticate($current_user->user_login, $user_data['new_password']);
```

Comment: `wp_signon` выдаёт такую же ошибку.

Если после изменения пароля обновить страницу то нужно будет заново авторизоваться. почему так?